# Spring Boot 1.4.0 Circular Dependency Exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot 1.4.0 and am getting a circular dependency exception when compiling the code. My project structure is standard and an identically structured project works well using Spring Boot 1.3.5. I am hoping to find a way to remove the circular dependency exception.

Project Gradle File

```
dependencies {
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb')
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
  compile('org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas')
  testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

My project structure follows a standard MVC pattern including from bottom to top, MongoDB, Repository, Service, Controller, UserDetailsService and Spring Security Configuration.

As Follows:

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface LrqaPersonRepository extends MongoRepository<LrqaPerson,       String> {

  public LrqaPerson findByEmail(String email);
  public List<LrqaPerson> findByCountry(String country);

}
```

Service

```
 @Autowired
      public LrqaPersonService(LrqaPersonRepository lrqaPersonRepository,
                             PasswordEncoder encoder){

        this.lrqaPersonRepository = lrqaPersonRepository;
        this.encoder = encoder;
        }   


        public LrqaPerson findSingleLrqaPerson(String id){
              logger.info("LrqaPersonService method findSingleLrqaPerson() invoked: " + LocalDateTime.now());
              LrqaPerson lrqaPerson = this.lrqaPersonRepository.findOne(id);
              return lrqaPerson;
          }
```

UserDetailsService

```
@Service("personDetailsService")
public class PersonDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

private static final Logger logger =     LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonDetailsService.class);

private List<GrantedAuthority> auth;

@Autowired
LrqaPersonService personService;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    logger.info("LrqaPersonDetailsService loadUserByUsername() invoked: " + LocalDateTime.now());
    LrqaPerson person = personService.findLrqaPersonByEmail(email);

    if (person == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid Email Username");
    }

    if (person.getAuthority().equals("user")) {
        logger.info("LrqaPersonDetailsService authority privilege detected: " + person.getAuthority());
        auth = AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_USER");
    }

    if (person.getAuthority().equals("admin")) {
        logger.info("LrqaPersonDetailsService authority privilege detected: " + person.getAuthority());
        auth = AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER");
    }

    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
            email, person.getPassword(), auth);

}
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
public class PeopleController {


private final LrqaPersonService personService;
private static final Logger logger =   LoggerFactory.getLogger(PeopleController.class);

@Autowired
public PeopleController(LrqaPersonService personService){
    this.personService = personService;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/allpeople", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<LrqaPerson> getAllLrqaPeople(){
    logger.info("LrqaGenericController method getAllLrqaPeople() invoked: " + LocalDateTime.now());
    List<LrqaPerson> lrqaPeople = this.personService.findAllLrqaPersons();
    return lrqaPeople;
}
```

The Exception I get on running ./gradlew bootRun --debug is:

Exception

```
11:12:36.141 [QUIET] [system.out] ***************************
11:12:36.141 [QUIET] [system.out] APPLICATION FAILED TO START
11:12:36.141 [QUIET] [system.out] ***************************
11:12:36.141 [QUIET] [system.out] 
11:12:36.141 [QUIET] [system.out] Description:
11:12:36.142 [QUIET] [system.out] 
11:12:36.142 [QUIET] [system.out] There is a circular dependency between 4   beans in the application context:
11:12:36.142 [QUIET] [system.out]   - peopleController defined in file   [/Users/frank***/Development/IntelliJ/springAngularJSTutorial/build/classes/main  /org/frank/***/controller/PeopleController.class]
11:12:36.142 [QUIET] [system.out]   - lrqaPersonService defined in file [/Users/frank***/Development/IntelliJ/springAngularJSTutorial/build/classes/main/org/frank/***/service/LrqaPersonService.class]
11:12:36.142 [QUIET] [system.out]   - securityConfig
11:12:36.142 [QUIET] [system.out]   - personDetailsService (field org.frank.***.service.LrqaPersonService org.frank.***.security.PersonDetailsService.personService)
11:12:36.142 [QUIET] [system.out]   - lrqaPersonService
11:12:36.142 [QUIET] [system.out] 
11:12:36.142 [QUIET] [system.out] 
11:12:36.180 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: FAILED
```

My security Configuration is as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Resource(name = "personDetailsService")
private PersonDetailsService personDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void configureAuth(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("****").password("****").roles("USER");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user", "/index.html", "/home.html", "/login.html", "/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .formLogin().and()
            .httpBasic().and()
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    ;
}
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    return encoder;
}
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws     Exception {              builder.userDetailsService(personDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
}
```

I have noticed some coverage of the issue on various forums online. It would be a great help to me if there is a resolution to the circular dependency exception and any place I can find an explanation about why the Boot 1.3.5 application structure does not generate the exception. That is, what changed between 1.3.5 and 1.4.0. in relation to this [if there is a simple description suitable for this question].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the message says, there's a circular dependency between four beans in your application. In more detail that cycle is:

- `PeopleController` depends on `LrqaPersonService`
- `LrqaPersonService` depends on `PasswordEncoder` which is produced by `SecurityConfig`
- `SecurityConfig` depends on `PersonDetailsService`
- `PersonDetailsService` depends on `LrqaPersonService`

You need to break that cycle somehow.

Looking at the code, it's not clear why `PasswordEncoder` is being injected into `LrqaPersonService` as it appears to be unused. The simplest fix may be to remove `PasswordEncoder` from `LrqaPersonService`.

If you can't do that for some reason, I think you could break the cycle by moving the `@Bean` method for the `PasswordEncoder` from `SecurityConfig` to a separate `@Configuration` class.